# MSSQL Parsing Name into two new columns and adding to the same table

Tags: sql-server

I am using sql server and I am trying to figure out how to select the `vp_timesheetpunch.personfullname [Assoc Name]` which is a view and then parse it because the results show up "last name, first name Middle Name". I am trying to add three more columns after the `vp_timesheetpunch.personfullname [Assoc Name]` to show First Name in one column then last name and somehow throw in a middle name column (incase there is a middle name) in another right after the `Assoc Name`.

```
     select
            vp_timesheetpunch.personnum [Assoc ID],
            vp_timesheetpunch.personfullname [Assoc Name],
            vp_timesheetpunch.laborlevelname1 [Department],
            vp_timesheetpunch.laborlevelname4 [Salary Code],
            vp_timesheetpunch.eventdate [Shift Date],
            shiftassignmnt.shiftstartdate [Scheduled Start],
            vp_timesheetpunch.startdtm [Rounded Start],
            vp_timesheetpunch.inpunchdtm [Actual Start],
            vp_timesheetpunch.enddtm [Rounded End],
            vp_timesheetpunch.outpunchdtm [Actual End],
            vp_timesheetpunch.TIMEINSECONDS [Time in seconds],
            convert(decimal(7,2),vp_timesheetpunch.TIMEINSECONDS/3600.0) [Time in hours]
        from
            vp_timesheetpunch
        left outer join
            vp_punchexceptions
        on
            vp_timesheetpunch.timesheetitemid = vp_punchexceptions.timesheetitemid
        inner join
            timesheetitem
        on
            vp_timesheetpunch.timesheetitemid = timesheetitem.timesheetitemid
        inner join
            workedshift
        on
            timesheetitem.workedshiftid = workedshift.workedshiftid
        inner join
            shfasgnwshfmm
        on
            workedshift.workedshiftid = shfasgnwshfmm.workedshiftid
        inner join
            shiftassignmnt
        on
            shfasgnwshfmm.shiftassignid = shiftassignmnt.shiftassignid
        where
            --limit rows to the specified pay period
            vp_timesheetpunch.eventdate = '1/22/2019'
            --exclude rows that are missing data
            and vp_timesheetpunch.inpunchdtm is not null
            and vp_timesheetpunch.outpunchdtm is not null
            --limit rows to shifts with exceptions
        order by
            vp_timesheetpunch.personnum,
            vp_timesheetpunch.eventdate
```

Edit: I tried using case to parse but was unsuccessful with my attempts.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parsing names can be kind of ugly. Assuming you really have the two patterns something like this should work.

```
declare @FullName varchar(50) = 'Brierton, David H'

select LastName = case when parsename(replace(replace(@FullName, ',', ''), ' ', '.'), 3) is null
        then parsename(replace(replace(@FullName, ',', ''), ' ', '.'), 2)
        else parsename(replace(replace(@FullName, ',', ''), ' ', '.'), 3)
    end
    , FirstName = case when parsename(replace(replace(@FullName, ',', ''), ' ', '.'), 3) is null
        then parsename(replace(replace(@FullName, ',', ''), ' ', '.'), 1)
        else parsename(replace(replace(@FullName, ',', ''), ' ', '.'), 2)
    end
    , case when parsename(replace(replace(@FullName, ',', ''), ' ', '.'), 3) is not null
        then parsename(replace(replace(@FullName, ',', ''), ' ', '.'), 1)
    end
```

But whenever there is a question about names in the database I feel I have to share this link. https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Answer (score 1):

You need a comma after  ) AS LAST_NAME...

```
 ) AS LAST_NAME,
```

UPDATE:  Below is your code with only one object.  Can you confirm it works?

```
Select CASE WHEN 0 = CHARINDEX(' ',vp_timesheetpunch.personfullame)
     THEN NULL  --no more spaces?  assume rest is the first name
     ELSE SUBSTRING(
                      vp_timesheetpunch.personfullame,1
                     ,CHARINDEX(' ',vp_timesheetpunch.personfullame)-1
                   )  END AS MIDDLE_NAME
        ,SUBSTRING(
                      vp_timesheetpunch.personfullame,1 + CHARINDEX(' ',vp_timesheetpunch.personfullame)
                      ,LEN(vp_timesheetpunch.personfullame)
                  ) AS LAST_NAME
From vp_timesheetpunch
```

Comment: Seems to me that adding this required comma has only shed light on other issues. That missing comma is critical to this query even parsing.

Comment: Are you suggesting that your newly edited information in your question (without your attempt to parse the name) is working properly?  I ask because it appears to me your previous parsing code works and that you only missed the comma...  You then say you have an error finding the vp_timesheetpunch object?  Can you simplify your effort to confirm smaller parts are working?  See my update to test your invalid object...

Comment: How did the chosen answer resolve the invalid object?

Comment: I agree....no clue what that missing object was all about. And certainly as originally posted the missing comma would have crippled that query.

Comment: I appreciate your not leaving me confused.  Your answer to the actual question is clearly the most accurate.... cheers